# Assembly code running infinite loop

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, masm

so I've been tasked with writing a c++ code that uses an Assembly program, which should be binary search.

Here is how the c++ call looks like:

`index = AsmBinarySearch(value, numbers, SIZE)`

Here is how the Assembly code looks like:

```
TITLE AsmBinarySearch Procedure (AsmBinarySearch.asm)

.586
.model flat,C

AsmBinarySearch PROTO, searchValue:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD

.data

.code

AsmBinarySearch PROC USES edi, searchValue:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD

mov eax,arrayPTR
mov ecx,arrayPTR
add ecx,count
@@:
cmp eax,ecx
jg not_found
mov edx,eax
add edx,ecx
shr edx,1
xchg DWORD PTR [edx],eax
cmp eax,searchValue
xchg DWORD PTR [edx],eax
jg search_right
jl search_left
mov eax,edx
sub eax,arrayPTR
ret
search_right:
mov ecx,edx
jmp @B
search_left:
mov eax,edx
jmp @B
not_found:
mov eax,-1
ret
AsmBinarySearch ENDP
END
```

The problem is that this Assembly code runs an infinite loop when called from the c++ program. So how do I fix this code?

Please help me fix this code completely, so it does what is intended, because at this point, mainly because I am a beginner, I cannot find any solution to fix that.

Comment: Poor @Jester is going to pull his hair out

Comment: @MichaelPetch haha, true that. I just can't get to make this work, and I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: "I've been tasked" - by whom?  Can you tell them to go jump?  The C++ Standard Library provides [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), which would be a better option than wasting time on this.

Comment: It is some kind of a project required for school, and I found this interesting to do. But as you can see, I am not that skilled in Assembly to do that...

Comment: @Jester suggested in the other comments that you might want to use a debugger. Visual Studio has a very good one and would let you step into the function and watch the registers and memory to see why your code may be in that infinite loop. Using a debugger is a very valuable asset especially when programming in assembly language.

Comment: The code looks like crap: `mov edx,eax / add edx,ecx` makes edx point one past the end of the array of numbers, `shr edx,1` turns edx into complete crap (basically dividing the memory address by 2!), `xchg DWORD PTR [edx],eax` then tries to derefence the crap.  If you want to get working code, I suggest you write it in C++ then generate assembly output (e.g. `g++ -S`).

Comment: ok, I'm writing the code in C then, and will compile to assembly. Will let you know how it went.

Comment: The problem is not the language but the algorithm you are using. Re-write the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes, and I think the first causes your core problem (although maybe not the only problem):

1) in the following code,

```
mov eax,arrayPTR
mov ecx,arrayPTR
add ecx,count
```

you add the count to the address of arrayPTR, without taking into account the size of each array element; you need to multiply count by 4 to match the DWORD definition of the array.  Note that this will search one quarter of your total array, and the array isn't sorted, which will cause the code to jump around randomly and in weird ways - consider if you have 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00, the first five values of your array will be treated as 1, 33554432, 131072, 512, 2, ...

2) Your jumps go to label @B, but there isn't a matching label; I assume this was a typo in your post, and the @@ is actually the jump destination - if not, your code is jumping to somewhere it shouldn't.

3) Your attempt to save the left side of the array,

```
xchg DWORD PTR [edx],eax
cmp eax,searchValue
xchg DWORD PTR [edx],eax
```

is really ugly, especially considering that you have ebx free at this point.  Note that xchg shouldn't trash the flags following the comparison, but even if it doesn't, this is really slow as well as really ugly.

4) The address computation is valid for addresses that don't overflow (and these shouldn't), but I suggest documenting this sort of code to explain how/why it works, especially for code you post on SO in the future, since the comments indicate that some don't understand address arithmetic.